# AWS S3 object delete while downloading

Tags: amazon-s3

What happens when you are downloading an AWS S3 object and you delete the object when the download is in progress? Will the download complete with full object? Or will the download be partial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's one funny question, and I've just did an experiment by below step:

1. Uploaded a 100mb video onto my s3 bucket.
2. Download it with my browser.
3. Instantly delete the file on the s3 console with browser.

OR
3. Instantly delete it with PHP deleteObjects function.

Result: Download still goes on until its completion. No file size loss at all.